# TCP connection not closing in infinite loop

Tags: php, nginx, networking, tcp

There is a video streaming script built on PHP

A server listening on port 9090 accepts a client's connection and then initiates a video stream transfer to the client.

My server doesn't notice that the user is disconnected from the internet and when I check with netstat it stays "`ESTABLISHED`".

This problem only occurs in a situation where the user's internet is interrupted involuntarily.

Where and how should I look for the solution to this problem!

```
In Nginx config? 
In the PHP configuration? 
On Linux TCP mechanism?
```

Does this have a timeout option for connections that interrupt the flow from the infinite loop but still appear to be connected?

Comment: What do you mean with "disconnect" - browser close or loss of internet connectivity? And how long after disconnect you checked? Note that a short loss of connectivity is something TCP is supposed to recover from. A longer loss of connectivity should be detected though by the server at least if it is actively sending data.

Comment: Streams are served in video players rather than browsers. The problem does not occur when the user closes the player or browser while watching the stream and I can understand that the user is disconnected. However, this is not possible when the user is unintentionally disconnected from the internet while downloading the stream! @SteffenUllrich

Comment: How long after the connectivity loss did you check? And was streaming still active at this time, i.e. did the server actually try to deliver data (Check value if Send-Q in netstat)?

Comment: The Send-Q value remains constant when the user's internet is disconnected unintentionally.
I can understand that the client is not connected as the Send-Q value remains constant. Send-Q, which is constantly changing while the user is watching the flow, starts to show a constant value when the connection is disconnected and the connection does not close by itself for a very long time. I don't know how long it took. I guess I'm wrong in assuming that my client is watching the flow in my user control panel when Send-Q is at a fixed value. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: *" for a very long time"* - please be more specific, I have no idea what you consider as long. Several seconds, few minutes, hours?

Comment: I'm sure it's longer than 5 minutes

Comment: See https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/#busyestabsocketisnotforever how long it might take to  stop retrying delivery - about 16 minutes in default setup. See also there what you need to tune if you want to have this shorter: net.ipv4.tcp_retries2